# How to display unroutable tracks early in eagle autorouting process

Tags: eaglecad, wire, trace, autorouter

I felt like I spent a week trying to route the same circuit. I then look in the manual for hints, and it talks about how the status of the autorouter includes the number of tracks that it believes are unroutable. The value in the status bar is "conn: aa/bb/cc" where cc is the number of unroutable tracks.

Rather than me wait several minutes until the router has exhausted all possible connections, is there a way that the moment I see it can't route a track I could just stop it and have it display only the airwires showing what can't be routed?

selecting the ratsnest tool after stopping the autorouter will not work because that will make all unfinished tracks as airwires, not just the unroutable ones.

and idea?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can tell that there will be unrouteable tracks, or which tracks won't be routeable, until you've tried to route the whole board.

Which tracks are unrouteable, and how many are unrouteable, will depend on the order in which you (or the autorouter) routes things.

(edit)
If things appear unrouteable, moving components around may make the board routable.  With experience, you can see, while placing components, where you may have routing problems, so you can shift things to avoid those problems.

Comment: I agree. Routing in this context should be (for the general case, not for special cases like the schematics actually being a planar graph) NP-complete, ie. fastest way to know whether possible is to do.

Comment: First I try a finer grid then I shift things around. I think I'm on my millionth attempt to route the same board, so any kind of help from the autorouter is a benefit.

Comment: I consider routing a complex board to be a video game that can be very hard to win.  I think a human can usually out-perform an autorouter, as we can look at the whole board and see alternate routes or potential adjustments, where the autorouter just looks at getting the current track routed.  Manually routing a board does take practice, and (usually) gets better with experience.